# How to split file in muliple files with findall

Tags: python, split, findall

I want to split my file in mutiple files in python. So i find findall function to do this works.

My file contain :

```
**05/02/2020

- Test PC


- Electricite 
W=10
PUI=5



- Test MAPS
Nothing for now
- Date/Hours
DateTest=12h14
DateFinish=13h18

**05/02/2020
```

So, i use code as below to split this file with '- ' but it dosen't split very well.

```
import re

def main():

  with open('mesfile.log', 'r') as f:
      data = f.read()

  found = re.findall(r'\n*(- .*?\- .*?)\n*', data, re.M | re.S)

  [open(str(i)+'.txt', 'w').write(found[i-1]) for i in range(1, len(found)+1)]

if __name__=="__main__":
  main()
```

**Output Expected**

```
File 1 contains
- Test PC

File 2 contains
- Electricite 
W=10
PUI=5

File 3 contains
- Test MAPS
Nothing for now

 File 4 contains
- Date/Hours
DateTest=12h14
DateFinish=13h18

**05/02/2020
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get those results because the pattern `\n*(- .*?\- .*?)\n` matches 2 times the hyphen in the capturing group.

What you could do instead is match a lines starting with a hyphen and spaces, and then match all lines that do not start with that pattern.

Then store the matches in separate files.

```
^- .*(?:\r?\n(?!- ).*)*
```

- `^` Start of line
- `- .*` Match - and space, then match any char except a newline till the end
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!- )` Assert what is directly to the right is not `-` and a space
  - `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
- `)*` Close non capture group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WAtJ4y/1)

**Note** that you don't need `re.S` anymore.

For example

```
found = re.findall(r'^- .*(?:\r?\n(?!- ).*)*', data, re.M)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, which is way simpler and faster than using `re`:

```
with open('mesfile.log', 'r') as f:
    data = [i.strip() for i in f]

contents = []
for line in data :
    if line.startswith('-') :  # check for '-' separator
        contents.append([])
    if len(contents) > 0 :     # ignore everything before the first separator
        contents[-1].append(line)

for i,text in enumerate(contents) :
    with open( 'file_%05d.txt' % i, 'w') as fout :
        fout.write( '\n'.join( text ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
res = []
#read content
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith("*") or not line:continue   #skip empty line or date lines
        if line.startswith("-"):
            res.append([line])
        else:
            res[-1].append(line)

#write data to file
for idx, data in enumerate(res):
    with open("file_{}".format(idx), "w") as infile:
        infile.writelines(data)
```